# Android 2.3 doesn't pass cookie information for html5 audio tag Get request

Tags: android, cookies, html5-audio

I am trying to play a media file using html5 audio tag in android 2.3 from a secure site but I notice that on the Get request, android 2.3 isnt passing the cookie information from the browser to the server causing a 
'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily' 
response from the server back to the login page for reauthentication. I tried the same request on IOS mobile browser, chrome, safari, IE and the cookie information is sent on each request. Whats more puzzling is also that on img tag request, the cookie information is sent on the android browser.

My question is, is anyone aware if this is just an implementation bug on android 2.3 audio tag or am I missing an parameter to allow the cookie information to be passed?

thanks for any help

Comment: Probably related (video embed), or even the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32181185/1066234

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the browser doesn't send the request for the audio-tag by itself but instead delegates this to stagefright. Sadly Stagefright (on Android 2.3) doesn't send any cookies at all...

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem.
In my case I see a specific User-Agent:

```
User-Agent: HTC Streaming Player htc_wwe / 1.0 / htc_ace / 2.3.3
```

So, maybe, playing is performed by device player, that does not send browser cookies.